# trace $(ADA^{-1})=$ trace $(D)$ in infinite dimensions?

Tags: operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $X$ be a separable Hilbert space, $D$ nonnegative definite (by which I also mean self-adjoint) and trace class operator on $X$.  Let $A$ be a compact and injective operator with dense range $R$, so that $A^{-1}$ is densely defined.  Define $B=ADA^{-1}$ on $R$ and assume that $B$ is bounded.  Then it can be extended to the closure of $R$, which is $X$.  Assume that $B$ is also trace class.

**Question:** is it true that trace$(B)=$trace$(D)$?

Here are some thoughts.

(1) This is true in the finite-dimensional case, of course.

(2) This is true if $A$ is trace class and $DA^{-1}$ is bounded.

(3) This is true if $A$ and $D$ commute:  $AD=DA$.

(4) Let $(v_k)$ be an basis of $X$ with $Dv_k=\lambda_kv_k$, and let $u_k=Av_k$.  Then $Bu_k=\lambda_k u_k$, so $(u_k)$ are eigenvectors of $B$ but they are not orthogonal.  Heuristically, these are the only eigenvectors of $B$ (if $Bv=\lambda v$, then $DA^{-1}v=\lambda A^{-1}v$;  this is not a proof, of course).  So the question is somehow asking:  does the trace equal the sum of eigenvalues even if the eigenvectors are not orthogonal?

(5) I do not mind assuming things about the rate of decay of the eigenvalues of $D$ or the singular values of $A$ if it helps to get a positive answer.  There is also some more structure in my particular case, but I don't think that it is relevant:  in my case $A$ is a product of positive definite operators, one is Hilbert--Schmidt and the other bounded.

Comment: I think this follows by considering finite rank approximations $APDPA^{-1}$ and using the finite-dimensional case for this, but I haven't thought it through carefully.

Comment: Thanks Christian.  I also tried to do something of this sort but couldn't quite get the details right.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is compact, $A^{-1}$ is bounded by the bounded inverse theorem. Then, since $D$ is trace class, $DA^{-1}$ is also trace class. Finally, since $A$ is compact, the result follows $\mathrm{tr}[(A)(DA^{-1})]=\mathrm{tr}[(DA^{-1})(A)]=\mathrm{tr}(D)$.

Comment: The inverse of a compact operator in an infinite dimensional space is never bounded.

Comment: As @HansEngler notes, inverses of compact operators, if densely defined, are never bounded. Think of the example on $\ell^2$ that sends standard basis elements $e_n$ to $e_n/n$. (The finite-rank compact operators don't have inverses' eigenvalues going to infinity, but they also do not have dense image...)

Comment: @HansEngler and paul garrett, sorry, of course you are right. The bounded inverse theorem assumes bijectivity which not true for a compact operator in an infinite dimensional space as 0 is in the spectrum.